# 'Error en el documento XML (2, 2).' No se esperaba <info xmlns=''>

Tags: c#, xml, clase

Realizando el ejemplo de este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912483/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-this-xml-document-to-my-object) me encuentro con un error al momento de deserializar el objeto location y room:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Location locations = new Location();
            Room rooms = new Room();

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
            };

            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\temp\locations.xml", settings))
            {
                #region Deserializar location

                XmlSerializer deserializerLoc = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location), new XmlRootAttribute("location"));

                locations = (Location)deserializerLoc.Deserialize(reader);

                Location xmlDataLocation = locations;

                #endregion

                #region Deserializar room

                XmlSerializer deserializerRom = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Room));

                rooms = (Room)deserializerRom.Deserialize(reader);

                Room xmlDataRoom = rooms;

                #endregion

                Console.Write("cuartos : " + rooms.ToString());

                Console.Write("locaciones: " + locations);

            }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Lo que he consultado es que falta un espacio de nombres pero ya realice el proceso y resulta otro error en la misma linea opte por dejar sin espacio de nombre el xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <info >
  <locations>
   <location name="New York">
    <Buildings>
     <Building name="Building1">
      <Rooms>
        <Room name="Room1">
          <Capacity>18<Capacity>
        <Room>
        <Room name="Room2">
          <Capacity>6<Capacity>
        <Room>
      <Rooms>
    <Building>

    <Building name="Building2">
      <Rooms>
        <Room name="RoomA">
          <Capacity>18<Capacity>
        <Room>
      <Rooms>
    <Building>
  <Buildings>
<location>
<location name="London">
  <Buildings>
    <Building name="Building45">
      <Rooms>
        <Room name="Room5">
          <Capacity>6<Capacity>
        <Room>
      <Rooms>
    <Building>
  <Buildings>
  <location>
<locations>
</info>
```

La primera pregunta es porque sucede este error?

la segunda pregunta esta bien codificado llevar los datos del xml al objeto, lo necesito para ciertos tags del XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La raiz del archivo XML es un tag `<info>` y en el código:

```
 XmlSerializer deserializerLoc = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Location), new XmlRootAttribute("location"));
```

Le estás indicando al serializador que lo que va a encontrar es un `Location` por eso el error de que no se esperaba `<info>`.

Tienes que hacer como en el ejemplo:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Info));
```

Comment: pensé en un momento con el código saltarme el root